# String Reverse in Tibco Spotfire

Tags: tibco, spotfire

How to reverse a string in Tibco Spotfire ?
Spotfire provides lot of in built functions but there are some function as mentioned above are missing. 
But that can be achieved as mentioned below.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done in many ways a simple method is as follows :

Use TERR Functions :

TERR_String("output <- sapply(lapply(strsplit(input1, NULL), rev), paste, collapse='')",)

This will reverse entire column content.